# How to get integer or float value after matching couple words in PHP regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string with integer and float value. Now I want to extract the value by matching couple of words.

My string looks like the following text. Every string has **balance is** text. Now I want to get the balance amount by PHP regular expression.

```
 $str_demo_one = "210:Recharge request of TK 200 for mobile no. 1789000000, transaction ID BD07232231230125 is successful. Your account balance is TK 13769.98.";

$str_demo_two = "563:Recharge 150 Tk to 1880000000 is successful. Transaction number is R190723.2158.6600eb.Your new balance is tk 3852.55 TAKA. Thank You.";

$str_demo_three = "Recharge Request of TK 300 for mobile no 1942300468, transaction ID R190723.2152.2201e1 is successful. your account balance is TK 5434.72.";

$str_demo_four = "Recharge 650 Tk to 16300000 is successful. Transaction number is R190723.1106.710166.Your new balance is 5921.18 TAKA. Thank You.";

$str_demo_five = "Transaction ID is 0718140110124179. 1531141036 has been recharged successfully with 89 Taka. Your new balance is 2529 Taka.";
```

I've tried with flowing code

`preg_match_all('/(balance is)(\D*)(\d+)/i',$str,$matches);`

it only returns integer value not returning float value.

Comment: Show us your attempt(s) to achieve the same.

Comment: preg_match_all('/(balance is)(\D*)(\d+)/i',$str,$matches);

Comment: Please edit the question to include relevant details instead of posting them as comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex;

`balance is (?:t(?:k|aka))?\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) /ig`

This will work if the unit is "tk" or "taka".

Note the use of `/i` flag for case-insensitive match.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IzdBP3/4)

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern you are not taking the decimal part into account. You might update your pattern to `(balance is)(\D*)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

If you only want the match, you could make use of \K for forget what was matched, omit the capturing groups and make the decimal part optional.

```
\bbalance is \D*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TkJ74l/1)